# Replacing consecutive embedded blanks with another character in SAS

Tags: replace, sas

I'm trying to replace embedded spaces in one of my variables (`QPR`) with a new character. Here is my (abbreviated) code:

```
data sas2;
   input QPR $ & 1-9;
   QPR=tranwrd(strip(QPR)," ","0");
run;

proc print data=sas2;
run;
```

The `tranwrd` function seems to work for observations with one embedded blank; however, it does not work when there are two blanks in a row.

For example, `234 2345` becomes `23402345`, but `234  345` becomes `234` (i.e., The rest gets cut off, I assume because of `strip`). Instead, I want `23400345`.

I also tried `tranwrd` without the `strip` function, but I go from `234  345` to `23400000` instead. `Translate` does the same thing.

Any ideas on why this won't work and how to fix it? Alternatively, are there easier/better ways to do this in the `data` step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "&" symbol in your input statement causes SAS to stop reading the data after two spaces.  After SAS stops reading the data, it pads the rest of the string with spaces up to a total length of 9 chars. This is why you had a bunch of zeros at the end of the string when you didn't use strip.  Removing the "&" should fix it.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you for the explanation! I appreciate it.